# How can i do this layer style Effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

designers, In Photoshop i tried lot of times to make this layer style but i didn't. could anyone please tell me how can i do that. please have a look this URL

[image: http://postimg.org/image/tc1vj8bl9/]

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What have you tried? Show us where you've gotten on your own.

Comment: Looks like a simple deboss layer style to me. But yes, please be more explicit on what you've tried and where you're stuck. Oh, and welcome to GDSE!

Comment: I just want to make that layer style but what i tried please have a look:

http://postimg.org/image/6x3a54d1b/

Comment: I closed your question because Im not sure if you're asking to create a mockup that looks like it has an emboss??  What in the design are you trying to do?  What have you tried?  Are you asking to know how to make the design on multiple layers?  Please be clear as best you can in what your intended goal is.  I understand English may not be your first language but please be as descriptive as you can and we can edit your English for you.

Comment: I dont try to explain more thats why i upload screen shot. so my question was simple,how can i make layer style. anyway thanks, Matt

Answer (score 1):

The actual effect you are looking for, as previously stated in the comments, is called **debossing** and would typically be handled by the company printing your business cards.

If you just want to create this effect in Photoshop, I would do it as follows.  This is just a VERY quick attempt and you will have to do more tweaking of the settings on your own.  I just figured this would serve as a good starting point:

Final Result:

[image: card]

I used a shape layer for that debossed area.  Photoshop has this shape built in, just look under `Custom Shapes`

[image: shape]

It's this one:

[image: shape2]

I filled the shape with Black, blending mode as Multiply, and set the Fill to 5%.

Then I used these settings:

[image]

Like I said, this is just a very quick start and was only meant to get you headed in the right direction.  You will have to try different settings to find what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks John Manly.I had also try this way. may be you make me perfect.Thanks again.